# Chrome Javascript: Automatically clicking a link with a specific text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

How can i click only on 1 link with the right content if both have the same class?

```
<a href='#' class='unfollow' onclick='alert("1");'>Click me!</a>
<a href='#' class='unfollow' onclick='alert("2");'>And me!</a>
```

i want to click for example on the link with And me! only can you help me please?

Comment: Do you mean to programatically click on the link? Why do you want to do that? Wouldn't it be easier to call the onclick handler directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
[].slice.call(links).forEach(function(link) {
  if (link.innerHTML == 'And me!') {
    setInterval(function() {
      link.click();
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

```html
<a href='#' class='unfollow' onclick='alert("1");'>Click me!</a>
<a href='#' class='unfollow' onclick='alert("2");'>And me!</a>
```

Comment: how can i make it run infinite?

Comment: @SDSDFsafad `while(true) { link.click(); }`

Comment: how can i add dealy to a while?

Comment: @SDSDFsafad if you want to have delay in each loop then you can use `setInterval(function() { link.click(); }, 5000);` it will execute click in every 5 seconds. The time is in miliseconds.

Comment: var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
[].slice.call(links).forEach(function(link) {
  if (link.innerHTML == 'Delete') {
    while(true) { link.click(); }, 5000);
  }
});
tried this way not working

Comment: @SDSDFsafad  You still try to use while loop I said that you should use setInterval, see my updated answer.